# Adding a JPanel of a Game (that uses KeyListener) via Button Action Listener disables keylistener

Tags: java, button, actionlistener, keylistener

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game extends JPanel{
private static JFrame primary= new JFrame("Game");
private JButton x1;

public Game(){
    x1= new JButton("YES");
    x1.addActionListener(new LevelChoice(1));
    add(x1);
}

public static void setScreen(JPanel jp){


    //primary.removeAll();
    //System.out.println("hi");
    //primary.revalidate();
    //primary.repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
    /*primary.add(new LevelHUD("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" +
            "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
            "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
            "xooomoooooooooooooox" +
            "xoooooooooxoooooooox" +
            "xoooooooooxooooomoox" +
            "xoooommoooxxxxooooox" +
            "xoooomooooooooooooox" +
            "xoooomooomooooooooox" +
            "xooomooooolooomoooox" +
            "xoooomcoooooooooooox" +
            "xooomococoooooooooox" +
            "xooomocoooloooooooox" +
            "xgoomocoooooooooooox" +
            "xcooooogooooooooooox" +
            "xocooooocoooooooooox" +
            "xoococooolooogooooox" +
            "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));*/

    primary.add(new Game());



    primary.setResizable(false);
    primary.setVisible(true);
    primary.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    primary.pack();
}

private class LevelChoice implements ActionListener{

    private int level;

    public LevelChoice(int i){
        level=i;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Game.setScreen(new LevelHUD(gamelevel1));
        primary.add(new LevelHUD("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" +
                "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
                "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
                "xooomoooooooooooooox" +
                "xoooooooooxoooooooox" +
                "xoooooooooxooooomoox" +
                "xoooommoooxxxxooooox" +
                "xoooomooooooooooooox" +
                "xoooomooomooooooooox" +
                "xooomooooolooomoooox" +
                "xoooomcoooooooooooox" +
                "xooomococoooooooooox" +
                "xooomocoooloooooooox" +
                "xgoomocoooooooooooox" +
                "xcooooogooooooooooox" +
                "xocooooocoooooooooox" +
                "xoococooolooogooooox" +
                "xoooooooooooooooooox" +
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        revalidate();

    }

}


}
```

Ok so I have a game  with about 12 classes atm but I won't go into detail with that- My game involves a movement of the player using the arrow keys via key listener. This is my main class- Now what happens is this. I'm trying to make it so that a person can choose what level they want to play on- Level A or Level B. I then add a JPanel that contains that game level for the user to play- If I add the game level in the main method, everything works fine!

When I click the button and THEN add the JPanel, however, the player can't move and that's about it- all the monsters in the level work perfectly, however.

Any thoughts? Does ButtonListener override KeyListener or something? BTW, setFocusable is set to true in the game level panel class already, so I doubt that's an issue

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListeners` require that the component they are listening to, to have focus, when you click a button, focus changes and the keys are no longer "sent" to your component.

You have two choices.  Change your code to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (preferred) or call `requestFocusInWindow` on the panel you want to receive key events

**Updated with example**

Simple example that demonstrates the core issue.  Focus MUST be returned to the component with the `KeyListener`, it's not good enough to focus it's child or parent component.

You should make sure that the focus request is made within the EDT, otherwise it is possible that it might be stolen

```
public class TestKeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestKeyListener();
    }

    public TestKeyListener() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                KeyPane keyPane = new KeyPane();
                frame.add(keyPane);
                frame.add(new ButtonPane(keyPane), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class KeyPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel keyed;
        public KeyPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            keyed = new JLabel("...");
            add(keyed);
            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocusInWindow();

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    keyed.setText(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(e.getKeyCode(), e.getModifiers()).toString());
                }

            });

            addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    keyed.setText("Focus gained");
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    keyed.setText("Focus lost");
                }

            });

        }

    }

    public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

        public ButtonPane(final Component focus) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton bad = new JButton("Steal Focus");
            JButton good = new JButton("Return Focus");
            good.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    focus.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });

            add(good);
            add(bad);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: LevelHUD lhud=new LevelHUD("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   
   primary.add(lhud);
   primary.revalidate();
   lhud.requestFocusInWindow();

ok, I tried this, but it didn't work...

Comment: Really?  Works fine for me, check updated.  Remember clicking a button gives focus to the button.